# How do I manipulate a list with a function in Python (global scope)?

Tags: python, list, global-scope

I have a list with integers and strings `l = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']` and want to write a function that takes the list and manipulates it in a way that it just contains integers afterwards.
The function output looks like what I want to have, but it doesn't change the "original" list.

```
def filter_list(l):
  temp =[]
  for item in l:
      if type(item) == int:
          temp.append(item)
  l = temp
  return l
```

```
Function output: [1, 2]
Variable explorer: [1,2,'a','b']
```

In contrast, the function

```
def manipulate(l):
    l.append("a")
    return l
```

```
Function output: [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'a']
Variable explorer: [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'a']
```

changes the "original" list.

1. What's the difference between theses 2 function, i.e. why does the
   second one manipulate my "original" list, but the first one doesn't?
2. How do I have to adjust function 1 in order to get the desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont' you set `l` as `global` ? `global l`

Comment: Think about what `l` is in the first function. It's the parameter, not the global, and reassigning a parameter has no effect outside of the function.

Comment: And in `manipulate()` you are mutating the object passed to it. `append` mutates list in place. So, `l` is changed. Don't change 1st function just do `l=filter_list(l)` and replace these `l = temp
  return l` with `return temp`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both `l = filter_list(l)` and flagging `l`as `global` inside my function, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, all objects are passed to functions by reference, meaning you **can** change the object passed to your function. That's why when you call the `append` method in your second example the list changes.

However, if you assign a different object to the argument that was passed (`l = temp`), then you change the reference itself and therefore can not make changes to the original object from the outer scope. That's not a problem in your case, though, because you return the new reference, as you should in this case.

Comment: So my thinking that with `l = temp` I replace the current value of `l` with `temp` is wrong? It's more that the reference from `l` to the original object gets replaced by a reference from `l`to `temp`, and once the function is exited, this reference gets deleted?

Comment: Almost - `l` doesn't become a reference from `l` to `temp`, it becomes another reference to what `temp` is referencing. But yes, I think you basically got it.

Comment: Thanks! The reference thing changes a lot in terms of how I thought variables work. Will have to dig deeper into this topic for sure though.

Comment: Yes, it's definitly useful to understand. Note that this is different between languages. Check out C pointers for a deeper understanding of this.